# How to get the elements from a JSON.Element with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to create a stock analysis alert app, and I want to get the first result from a JSON response from the Alpha Vantage API. I use the following code to do so.

```
    @IBAction func saveIsPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let ticker = tickerTextField.text, let indicator = indicatorTextField.text, let timeInterval = timeIntervalTextField.text, let seriesType = seriesTypeTextField.text, let timePeriod = timePeriodTextField.text {
        stock.ticker = ticker
        stock.indicator = indicator
        stock.timeInterval = timeInterval
        stock.seriesType = seriesType
        stock.timePeriod = timePeriod



        print(stock.url)

        Alamofire.request(stock.url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in

            if response.result.isSuccess {

                print("Success")
                let stockJSON:JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print("Printing JSON")
                print(stockJSON)

                print("Printing Get Data")
                self.getData(json: stockJSON)


            } else {

                print("Result wasn't a success")
            }


        }



    }




}

func getData(json:JSON){

    if let data = json["Technical Analysis: BBANDS"].first {

        print(data)



    }

}
```

The problem is at the getData method, I only want to access the most recent element from the request, so I use json["Technical Analysis: BBANDS"].first to always get the first object from the request, however in this very object, there are three other objects that I want to access to. This JSON API request returns the following code:

```
 ("2018-04-05 15:45", {
  "Real Upper Band" : "1045.9855",
  "Real Middle Band" : "1018.0134",
  "Real Lower Band" : "990.0413"
})
```

That result is from the getDataJSON.first method, and since I already accessed the first element of the request, I want to further it more and access the other three elements within the former, that is the Middle, Lower and Upper Bands objects, however I cannot find a way to do so since it returns a JSON.Element that doesn't allow subscripts. What would be the best way to get the first element of a request and then access the elements of that first element.

Comment: Are you sure that this is what the API returns? This isn't valid JSON.

Comment: `{
  "Technical Analysis: BBANDS" : {
    "2018-04-05 15:45" : {
      "Real Upper Band" : "1045.9855",
      "Real Middle Band" : "",
      "Real Lower Band" : ""
    },
  },
  "Meta Data" : {
    "8: Time Zone" : "US\/Eastern Time",
    "2: Indicator" : "Bollinger Bands (BBANDS)",
    "1: Symbol" : "GOOG",
    "6.1: Deviation multiplier for upper band" : 2,
    "6.2: Deviation multiplier for lower band" : 2,
    "3: Last Refreshed" : "2018-04-06 16:00:00",
    "6.3: MA Type" : 0,
    "4: Interval" : "15min",
    "5: Time Period" : 60,
    "7: Series Type" : "close"
  }
}`

Comment: That is what it returns, so when I access with json["Technical Analysis: BBANDS"].first it gets me the first element of the whole json code, it was so long I really couldn't paste it all, but the idea is that within the ["Technical Analysis BBANDS"] object, there are a lot of dates, within that dates there are three objects. I want to access the most recent date and the three objects that come with them so I can turn them to doubles and save them to my model

Comment: Looks like an array with a string and then a dictionary? I would try `json["Technical Analysis: BBANDS"].first.array` or something like that to begin with.

Comment: Or maybe it's one of those tuples that SwiftyJSON likes to use. Try `json["Technical Analysis: BBANDS"].first.0` and `json["Technical Analysis: BBANDS"].first.1`

Comment: `if let data = json["Technical Analysis: BBANDS"].[0]` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can do it like this:

```
if let mostRecentElement = json["Technical Analysis: BBANDS"].max(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 }) {
    let dateString = mostRecentElement.0
    let values = mostRecentElement.1
}
```